# How test QTableView edition with QTest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, qt4, qtestlib

I would like to simulate edition of a cell of QTableView with QTest.

I have tried different approach but without any success:

```
qtableview->show(); 
/* I think that in my unit test I should no need 
that, could you confirm ? */

QModelIndex modelIndex = qtableview->model()->index(1,1); 
//I have tested that modelIndex is valid and that I retrieved expected data

/*First try: set the currentIndex on modelIndex 
thinking that keyClicks on qtableview will work 
on selected element of the tableview*/
qtableview->setCurrentIndex(modelIndex );
QTest::KeyClicks(qtableview,“Hello Word”);
QCOMPARE->index(1,1).data(), “Hello World”); // —> FAILED

/*Second approach
Get the cell widget*/
QWidget * qwidget = qtableview->indexWidget( modelIndex );
//—> No test since the qwidget is NULL… why ?

/*Third approach
Get the cell widget through the delegate*/
QWidget * qwidget = 
      qtableview->itemDelegate( modelIndex )->createEditor(qtableview,       
                                                           QStyleOptionViewItem(), 
                                                           modelIndex );
QTest::KeyClicks(qwidget ,“Hello Word”);
QCOMPARE->index(1,1).data(), “Hello World”); // —> FAILED
```

I have also added in the three aproaches without any success

```
QTest::mouseDClick(qtableview)
QTest::KeyClicks(qtableview,“Hello Word”);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure if that is the only problem but you are typing "Hello Word" and comparing that to "Hello World" which will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to process events after a widget is shown. QListView probably won't be doing anything if it's hidden (as it well should!). See if qWaitForWindowShown(qtableview) would do the trick. If that won't work, run the event loop directly by calling QCoreApplication::processEvents(). Have a look in qWaitForWindowShown, it probably spins an event loop anyway.